# Construct a 2D, 3x3 matrix with random numbers from 1 to 8 with no duplicates

Tags: python

Construct a 2D, 3x3 matrix with random numbers from 1 to 8 with no duplicates

```
import numpy as np
random_matrix = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(3,3))
print(random_matrix)
```

Comment: If we assume that the numbers are integers, there are 10 of them  ranging from 0 to 9. A 3x3 matrix will not contain all of them.

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question

Comment: There are 8 integers  ranging from 1 to 8.

Comment: yes so with one missing space

Comment: @qqq Please update the question with an actual example of the matrix you're actually asking for here. You're moving the goal-post of this question with each new edit, and if what I suspect you're asking for at the moment is true, then all of the current answers are invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy 
x = numpy.arange(0, 9)
numpy.random.shuffle(x)
x = numpy.reshape(x, (3,3))
print(numpy.where(x==0, '#', x))
```

Let me know, but with my solution, integers seems to be replaced by string.. i don't know if you care. Else, I will found an other solution

Comment: This does not include `0` nor does it change said `0` into `"#"`.

Comment: then, x = numpy.arange(0, 9), and for second part of response, I'll will update if nobody answer before me

Comment: Please update your post regardless if someone already has given an answer, because there are always multiple ways to solve a problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an answer where we don't have to rely on `numpy` then you can do this:

```
import random

# Generates a randomized list between 0-9, where 0 is replaced by "#"
x = ["#" if i == 0 else i for i in random.sample(range(10), k=9)]
print(x)

# Slices the list into a 3x3 format
newx = [x[idx:idx+3] for idx in range(0, len(x), 3)]
print(newx)
```

Output:

```
[6, 2, 7, 4, '#', 8, 9, 1, 3]
[[6, 2, 7], [4, '#', 8], [9, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works but is there a way to put it to 2D?

Comment: @qqq what do you mean? The list `newx` is 2D.

Comment: um..like a real 3x3 matrix form. sorry i dont know how to explain it better like not in a single column?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using a few steps:

1. Generate sequence of values (in some range) you would like to randomly select into matrix.
2. Take randomly some number of elements from this sequence to new sequence.
3. From this new sequence make matrix with wanted shape.

```py
import numpy as np
from random import sample

#step one
values = range(0,11)
#step two
random_sequence = sample(values, 9)
#step three
random_matrix = np.array(random_sequence).reshape(3,3)
```

Because you sample some number of elements, from unique sequence, that guarantee you uniqueness of new sequence, and then matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.random.choice` with `replace=False` to generate the `(3, 3)` array:

```py
np.random.choice(np.arange(9), size=(3, 3), replace=False)
```

Replacing `0` with `np.nan`:

```py
>>> np.where(x, x, np.nan)
array([[ 4.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 5., nan,  8.],
       [ 2.,  6.,  7.]])
```

However, I think Hampus Larsson's answer is better, as this problem is not appropriate for numpy if you intend to replace `0` with the string `"#"`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use numpy but random is enough

```
import random
numbers = list(range(9))
random.shuffle(numbers)
my_list = [[numbers[i*3 + j] for j in range(0,3)] for i in range(0,3)]
```